# How do I find the default ODE solver tolerances in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, ode

You can set the Absolute or Relative ODE solver tolerances in Matlab with the options structure from an `odeset` command. But how do I find the default values for the different ODE solvers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`odeset` documentation in R2018a](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html),

- relative tolerance has a default of $10^{-3}$
- absolute tolerance has a default of $10^{-6}$

You should also be able to see them by running `odeset` command without any arguments.

[image]